# In Bigquery, how can I convert stringified array of struct into a proper array?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to store the labels of each table in a dataset into a table containing (table_name, label_name, label_value) so that I can select table names with conditions on labels (for instance, a `WHERE label_name = 'xxx' and label_value = 'yyy'`).

With this query, I can extract a stringified array of struct, each containing the label name and the label value:

```
*
FROM `mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS`
WHERE option_name = 'labels'
```

Output looks like this:

```
WITH output AS
( 
SELECT "table_name_a" as table_name, "ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING>>" AS option_type, "[STRUCT(\"label_name_a_1\", \"label_value_a_1\"), STRUCT(\"label_name_a_2\", \"label_value_a_2\"), STRUCT(\"label_name_a_3\", \"label_value_a_3\")]" as option_value
UNION ALL
SELECT "table_name_b" as table_name, "ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING>>" AS option_type, "[STRUCT(\"label_name_b_1\", \"label_value_b_1\"), STRUCT(\"label_name_b_2\", \"label_value_b_2\"), STRUCT(\"label_name_b_3\", \"label_value_b_3\")]" as option_value
)

SELECT * FROM output
```

The intuitive approach would be to cast to an array and specify the structure:

```
SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING>>[STRUCT("label_name_a_1", "label_value_a_1"), STRUCT("label_name_a_2", "label_value_a_2"), STRUCT("label_name_a_3", "label_value_a_3")]
```

but I couldn't find a way to do it "dynamically" for each option_value

A terribly bad solution would be to transform the string and then use a JSON_EXTRACT but I think there might be a much better and simpler way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code sample to convert the option value string to `ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>` type:

```sql
DECLARE optionValue DEFAULT ((select option_value
FROM `zyun.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS`
WHERE option_name = 'labels'
  AND table_name = 'test'));

DECLARE label ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>> " || optionValue INTO label;

SELECT label;
```

Output:

```
SELECT label; -- at [9:1]
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                           label                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| [{"key":"aaa","value":"bbb"},{"key":"ccc","value":"ddd"}] |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Great! I'll just have to figure out how to run this on any number of tables (the goal is to schedule a query that will store in a table all labels and label values of each table in a dataset)